# GraphQL is there a way to get resolved Union type fields without explicit "...on" query?

Tags: java, graphql-java

I have the following Union defined in my schema file:

```
union ContentUnion = Content | Setting | Page | Picture
```

and for example this type defintion for *Setting*

```
type Setting {
    id: String!
    doctype: String!
    name: String!
}
```

I also have a working Type resolver for *ContentUnion*.

Using this query

```
{ 
 content(id: "113804"){
  ... on Setting{
      id
  }
 }
}
```

I am able to retrieve a value. But this feels weird for me because I do not understand why I have to explicitly tell that the Type is *Setting*. I thought that is what the TypeResolver is actually for?

I would like to simply use this query

```
  { 
     content(id: "113804"){
      id
    }
  }
```

But the result therefore is:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'id' in type 'ContentUnion' is undefined @ 'content/id'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 26
        }
      ],
      "description": "Field 'id' in type 'ContentUnion' is undefined",
      "validationErrorType": "FieldUndefined",
      "queryPath": [
        "content",
        "id"
      ],
      "errorType": "ValidationError",
      "path": null,
      "extensions": null
    }
  ],
  "extensions": null,
  "dataPresent": false
}
```

That is because the schema was not able to locate an *id* field on the *ContentUnion* union type since it is an union. I wonder if there is a way to get this to work maybe? Because it would remove a lot of headache for me in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you have to use the query with typed fragments.

Per [unions in the GraphQL specification](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/October2016/#sec-Unions), GraphQL Unions represent an object that could be one of a list of GraphQL Object types, but provides for no guaranteed fields between those types. **No** fields may be queried on union without the use of typed fragments.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a query that returns a Union, each of the union members will likely have a different structure. In a GQL query, you define what properties of a type you want to get returned.

If you have a Union return type, you therefor have to specify the wanted properties per union type:

```
{ 
 content(id: "113804") {
  
  ... on Setting{
      id
  }

  ... on Page{
      title
      slug
  }

 }
}
```

Depending on the type of content-element `113804`, you will get one of the four types, but you don't know beforehand what it will be. So, you have to give a property selection for each of the union types.